# `MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated` error

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90, gfortran, openmpi

I was facing a problem similar to the one discussed [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975994/mpi-send-recv-communicator-datatype-error), I have a MPI code which sum the lines of a vector which has a specific number of lines. I attach [the code here](http://speedy.sh/3cRUz/sum.f90).

When I try to compile with one core online `mpirun -n 1 ./program` I obtain:

`500000 sum    125000250000.00000  calculated by root process.
 The grand total is:    125000250000.00000`
Because I have only one core that compute the sum, it looks OK. But when I try to use multicore `mpirun -n 4 ./program` I obtain:

```
please enter the number of numbers to sum:
500000
[federico-C660:9540] *** An error occurred in MPI_Recv
[federico-C660:9540] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[federico-C660:9540] *** MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
[federico-C660:9540] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (your MPI job will now abort)
 sum    7812562500.0000000       calculated by root process.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun has exited due to process rank 1 with PID 9539 on
node XXXXX1 exiting without calling "finalize".
```

I also red similar problem for C program [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650732/openmpi-strange-output-error). The same with 2 and 3 processors.

Could someone help me to figure out what is the problem? My guess is that I made a mistake in the MPI_RECV calling related with the "sender".

Comment: Please inline your code here. If it's an MCVE, it should fit easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were a couple of problems in the code;

1. The most obvious problem was the syntax error with receive variable, *num_rows_to_receive*. You have received the rows calculated by the root_process in *num_rows_to_received*, but used the variable *num_rows_to_receive* for actually receiving the vector.

   `CALL mpi_recv (num_rows_to_receive, 1 , mpi_integer,
                root_process, mpi_any_tag, mpi_comm_world, 
                STATUS, ierr)
   CALL mpi_recv (vector2, num_rows_to_receive, mpi_real8, root_process,
                mpi_any_tag, mpi_comm_world, STATUS, ierr)`

This should resolve the error.

2. The second problem (atleast I could see that on my system) is the MPI_REAL datatype defaults to MPI_REAL4 and the size of the vector gets truncated. So we won't be able to receive the actual summation of all the elements. Changing mpi_real to MPI_REAL8 will fix the summation issue and you can get the exact summation value for all any number of ranks.

   `~/temp$ mpirun -n 8 ./a.out
   please enter the number of numbers to sum:
   500000
   sum    1953156250.0000000       calculated by root process.
   partial sum    5859406250.0000000       returned from process            1
   partial sum    9765656250.0000000       returned from process            2
   partial sum    17578156250.000000       returned from process            4
   partial sum    21484406250.000000       returned from process            5
   partial sum    13671906250.000000       returned from process            3
   partial sum    25390656250.000000       returned from process            6
   partial sum    29296906250.000000       returned from process            7
   The grand total is:    125000250000.00000`

Comment: give to me the answer. Many thanks for that. I appreciate. I can say the question could be closed, as I received the answer. Many thanks to all.